# Remote go-agent doesn't connect to go-server

Tags: go-cd, go-server, go-agent

Go-agent and go-server same version - v18.8.0. Server and agent are installed in different machines. In go-server/agents , the agent is not listed.  The agent configuration file in /etc/default/go-agent is updated with hostname of go server.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my question - the /etc/default/go-agent file is updated with the remote go-server url. After making this change, restarting the agent did not solve the problem. So, I went to ***restart the entire machine and now the remote go-agent gets listed in the go-server/agents***.

Anytime the server (go-server) goes down, it should be ensured that every machine/runtime running go-agent is restarted.

FYI - This is with go-version#18.8.0 and go-agent#18.8.0